# Code is not recognizing id inside a JS Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Heyo!
So I've been having this problem lately and it really annoys me, so I need this button do launch a piece of code using id=, when I use the code on the webpage it works perfectly fine but when I use it inside a JS Modal provided by Tingle.js is doesn't work, it just doesn't launch.

This is my Modal:

```
function showPending(data) {
var modal = new tingle.modal({
  footer: false,
  stickyFooter: false,
  cssClass: ['custom-class-1', 'custom-class-2']
});

var content = "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:25px;letter-spacing:2px;color:#379639;'>Success!</div>";
content+= "<div style='font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;text-align:center;color:#2B2E32;margin-bottom:25px;'>You've received an offer from our bot <b>" + data.bot + "</b></div>";
content+= "<div class='input-box' style='width:35%;background:#e8e8e8;margin:auto;padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:6px;padding-right:6px;'><div style='font-size:12px;letter-spacing:4px;text-align:center;color:#2B2E32'>Security Code</div><div style='font-size:2em;color:black;text-align:center;'>" + data.code + "</div></div>";
content+= "<div style='margin-top:30px;text-align:center;'><a style='background:#1E1E26;padding:9px 25px 9px 25px;border-radius:35px;;color:white;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:25px;' id='offerButton' href='https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/" + data.tid + "' target='_blank'>Offer</a>";
content+= "<a style='margin-left:5px;background:#1E1E26;padding:9px 25px 9px 25px;border-radius:35px;color:white;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:25px;' id='confirmButton' data-tid='0'>Claim</a></div>"
    $("#confirmButton").data("tid", data.tid);
    if (data.amount < 0) {
        if (data.state == 2 || data.state == 3 || data.state == 4 || data.state == 9) {
            $("#confirmButton").html("Confirm");
        } else {
                $("#confirmButton").html("Confirmed");
        }
}

modal.setContent(content);

modal.open();
```

}

This is the piece that I need to launch 'confirmButton'

```
<a style='margin-left:5px;background:#1E1E26;padding:9px 25px 9px 25px;border-radius:35px;color:white;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:25px;' id='confirmButton' data-tid='0'>Claim</a>
```

Comment: Anything in developers console?

Comment: you are trying to save data to the confirm button while it is still a string and not yet an object.

Comment: What would you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 0):

take out your anchor tag and use the button feature built into tingle

```
modal.setContent(content);

 if (data.state == 2 || data.state == 3 || data.state == 4 || data.state == 9)
{
    modal.addFooterBtn("Confirm", 
        'tingle-btn tingle-btn--primary', 
         function() {
             // put your confirm logic here
             modal.close();
    });
}
else {
    modal.addFooterBtn("Confirmed", 
        'tingle-btn tingle-btn--primary', 
        function() {
            // put your confirmed logic here
            modal.close();
    });
}

modal.open();
```

Comment: Well, I don't like the way the footer looks, and I'm having problems with this piece:

Comment: <a style='margin-left:5px;background:#1E1E26;padding:9px 25px 9px 25px;border-radius:35px;color:white;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:25px;' id='confirmButton' data-tid='0'>Claim</a>

Comment: You can make their buttons look like yours

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not a true modal so the cursor is not going to stop at modal.open, waiting for a response so you can try this... (also, I see you are already including jQuery)

```
                     // hard coded data for testing
                    var data = { amount: -1, state: 10 };

                    // this function makes sure that the dialog does not appear until the pages
                    // is fully loaded (this is probably why my second attempt did not work)
                    $(function ($) {
                        showPending(data);
                     });

                    function showPending(data) {
                        var modal = new tingle.modal({
                            footer: false,
                            stickyFooter: false,
                            cssClass: ['custom-class-1', 'custom-class-2']
                        });

                        var content = "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:25px;letter-spacing:2px;color:#379639;'>Success!</div>";
                        content += "<div style='font-size:12px;letter-spacing:1px;text-align:center;color:#2B2E32;margin-bottom:25px;'>You've received an offer from our bot <b>" + data.bot + "</b></div>";
                        content += "<div class='input-box' style='width:35%;background:#e8e8e8;margin:auto;padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-left:6px;padding-right:6px;'><div style='font-size:12px;letter-spacing:4px;text-align:center;color:#2B2E32'>Security Code</div><div style='font-size:2em;color:black;text-align:center;'>" + data.code + "</div></div>";
                        content += "<div style='margin-top:30px;text-align:center;'><a style='background:#1E1E26;padding:9px 25px 9px 25px;border-radius:35px;;color:white;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:25px;' id='offerButton' href='https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/" + data.tid + "' target='_blank'>Offer</a>";
                        content += "<a style='margin-left:5px;background:#1E1E26;padding:9px 25px 9px 25px;border-radius:35px;color:white;letter-spacing:1px;font-size:25px;' id='confirmButton' data-tid='0'>Claim This</a></div>"



                        modal.setContent(content);
                        if (data.state == 2 || data.state == 3 || data.state == 4 || data.state == 9) {
                            $("#confirmButton").text("Confirm");
                            $("#confirmButton").on("click", function () {
                                // take action to confirm
                                alert("confirm");
                                modal.close();
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#confirmButton").text("Confirmed");
                            $("#confirmButton").on("click", function () {
                                // take action to confirmed
                                alert("confirmed");
                                modal.close();
                            });
                        }
                        modal.open();
                    }
```

Comment: Okay, so I replaced the code, nothing happens when the buttons are clicked, I still pretty much a noob but I just feel like it doesn't detect it when the button is clicked.

Comment: Made a minor change to make sure the jquery is not executed until the page is loaded. I tested it and it worked inside my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Some extra info:  If you want to use their buttons but make them look like your buttons do this:

```
<style>
    /* Your style info copied from the anchor. */
    .tinglebtn {
        margin-left:5px;
        background:#1E1E26;
        padding:9px 25px 9px 25px;
        border-radius:35px;
        color:white;
        letter-spacing:1px; 
        font-size:25px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    // blah blah blah all the other code left out

    modal.setContent(content);
    modal.addFooterBtn('Comfirm', 'tinglebtn', function () {
                            // here goes some logic
                            modal.close();
                        });


</script>
```